# Finding first and last true values in a matrix

Tags: c#, arrays, matrix

I have a two-dimensional array cointaining bool values. I need my script to find the first and last 'true' values of the first line of the array and do the same for the second line (the matrix will always have two lines).
Below is an example of a matrix that I could have, values in yellow are the ones I have to execute instructions on:
[image]

I'm sorry if this has been asked before but I couldn't find anything useful.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi I'm sorry, I don't use the site often so I may have forgotten about some of the rules. Would it be useful if I edited my question providing some of my failed attempts to get to the solution, or is it too late?

Answer (score 2):

In case of 2D array, you can try *nested loops*; you, probably, want indexes of 1st and last `1`s:

```
  int[,] data = new int[,] {
    { 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0},
    { 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
  };

  (int first, int last)[] result = new (int first, int last)[data.GetLength(0)];

  for (int r = 0; r < data.GetLength(0); ++r) {
    int min = -1;
    int max = -1;

    for (int c = 0; c < data.GetLength(1); ++c) {
      //ToDo: change into "if (data[r, c]) {" if data is of type bool[,]
      if (data[r, c] == 1) {
        max = c;
        min = min < 0 ? c : min;
      }
    }

    result[r] = (min, max);
  }
```

Now you can operate with `result` array, e.g.

```
  int FirstRowLast = result[0].last;
  int SecondRowFirst = result[1].first;
```

Let's have look:

```
  Console.Write(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, result));
```

Outcome:

```
  (3, 5)
  (1, 4)
```

Answer (score 2):

```cs
using System;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        int[,] arr = new int[2, 10]{
            {0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0},
            {0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0}
        };
        
        int last = -1;
        int first = -1;
        
        for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
            
            for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++){
                if(arr[i,j] == 1){
                    
                    if(first == -1){
                        first = j;
                    }
                    
                    last = j;
                }
            }
            
            Console.WriteLine("Row " + i + " -> " + "First : " + (first + 1) + " | Last: " + (last + 1));
            first = -1;
            last = -1;
        }
    }
}
```

Output

```
Row 1 -> First : 4 | Last: 6
Row 2 -> First : 2 | Last: 5
```

In the output assume the first index is 1.

Comment: thank you! I'm still a bit confused because the console throws a 'index was outside the bounds of the array' while at the same time the script works perfectly and does everything it needs to do... i have no idea... but anyway, thank you for your time

Comment: Did you change the array size or something before run. If it is then you have to change respective values in the for loops as well?

Comment: the array size can vary but I used array.GetLength in the second for loop so it shouldn't be a problem...

Comment: Please create a dotnetfiddle with your code. I'll try to fix this. https://dotnetfiddle.net

Comment: aparently the 'first' value is still -1 the first time it does the Console.WriteLine, even when the matrix is all 1s. This is not a major issue since, as I said, the program works just fine, but anyway here's my code: https://dotnetfiddle.net/7QmLWF

Comment: Should be children[i, j]. Anc `value` is a C# keyword. Don't use it as an identifier. I change the code in dotnetfiddle. Please check.